# AE.net.Mail, How to move mail to a new folder in outlook

Tags: email, c#-4.0, outlook, move

How to move *mail* to a *new folder* in *outlook*?

My code:

```
using (ImapClient ic = new ImapClient(
                             imapAddr, 
                             myEmailID, 
                             myPasswd, 
                             ImapClient.AuthMethods.Login, 
                             portNo, 
                             secureConn)) 
{ 
     ic.SelectMailbox("INBOX"); 
     bool headersOnly = false; 
     Lazy<MailMessage>[] messages = ic.SearchMessages(SearchCondition.Unseen(), headersOnly);
     foreach (Lazy<MailMessage> message in messages) 
     { 
       MailMessage m = message.Value; 
     }
}
```

I try Google it but I can not find it .
Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: I move a new message to a varible type string.now I want to moving these message to a new folder in outlook

Comment: How does outlook fit in AE.net.mail? Isn't this more of an Outlook question about Rules? Maybe show some code to clarify?

Comment: I try it:using (ImapClient ic = new ImapClient(imapAddr, myEmailID, myPasswd, ImapClient.AuthMethods.Login, portNo, secureConn))
            {
                ic.SelectMailbox("INBOX");
                bool headersOnly = false;
                Lazy<MailMessage>[] messages = ic.SearchMessages(SearchCondition.Unseen(), headersOnly);

                foreach (Lazy<MailMessage> message in messages)
                {
                    MailMessage m = message.Value;

Comment: now I want move the message to another folder from inbox to a folder in outlook

Comment: I edited your question to insert your code. Did you already try `ic.MoveMessage(message, "some existing folder");`

Comment: thanks its work but only if I write message.uid.what is these UID??

Comment: Great! Add your solution as an answer

Comment: do you know how in these technologic I create a new folder in my outlook?

Comment: If I look at the [source code](https://github.com/andyedinborough/aenetmail/blob/master/ImapClient.cs) maybe `CreateMailbox` will work...

Comment: yes its work.thanks you very much!now I try o send an email to the sender.but I didn't find option to do it with these technologic do you know something about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to move a message to another folder do this:

```
ic.MoveMessage(message.Uid, "some existing folder");
```

The `uid` is the unique identifiier for the mailmessage. I assume it maps to the [message-id](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6.4) as described in RFC for Internet Message Format. Or otherwise to the [UNIQUEID](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-2.3.1.1) in the IMAP protocol.

to create a new folder use the this method:

```
ic.CreateMailbox("new mailbox name");
```

To send emails use an [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx), like the one that is supplied in the .net framework:

```
        using(SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("your smtp server.com"))
        {
            client.Send("from@example.com", 
                        "to@example.com",
                        "subject",
                        "Hello World");
        }
```

Comment: I know this is an old question, but in case someone has trouble like I have. You need to call the expunge method after calling the MoveMessage. I have been deleting and moving without success. Expunge was the key for me.

Comment: 5 years later and still relevant. Your comment saved my bacon :) @RobWhite